# X11 port forwarding with JAVA

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

In most case I'm using the following command to use one mouse/keyboard for multiple system

```
ssh user@host -X x2x -west -to :0
```

I'm searching the same solution in Java, I found the `ganymed` and `jsch`.

In the `geanymed` I found an example, I tried to extend:

```
Session sess = conn.openSession();          
sess.requestX11Forwarding("localhost", 6000, null, true);
```

Is it possible to do the same things(`ssh user@host -X x2x -west -to :0`) using t`ganymed` or `jsch`? If yes how, can anybody provide me a minimal example?

Comment: Note that the actual value of DISPLAY to use may be different when using X11 forwarding

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly execute the same command as ssh executable supports, but you can parse those parameters & arrange them accordingly[for each library/framework your are using] to get your job done .

For JSch, try http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/X11Forwarding.java. If your Java VM is operating in headless mode, you will require some minimal tweak to strip-out Swing based code.
here goes the example, straight copied from the reference:

```
public class X11Forwarding{
  public static void main(String[] arg){

String xhost="127.0.0.1";
int xport=0;

try{
  JSch jsch=new JSch();  

  String host=null;
  if(arg.length>0){
    host=arg[0];
  }
  else{
    host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                     System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                     "@localhost"); 
  }
  String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
  host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

  Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

  String display=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter display name", 
                     xhost+":"+xport);
  xhost=display.substring(0, display.indexOf(':'));
  xport=Integer.parseInt(display.substring(display.indexOf(':')+1));

  session.setX11Host(xhost);
  session.setX11Port(xport+6000);

  // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
  UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
  session.setUserInfo(ui);
  session.connect();

  Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");

  channel.setXForwarding(true);

  channel.setInputStream(System.in);
  channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

  channel.connect();
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
}

public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
  Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
  int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
         str,
         "Warning", 
         JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
         JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
         null, options, options[0]);
   return foo==0;
}

String passwd;
JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(20);

public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
public boolean promptPassword(String message){
  Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
  int result=
  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
  if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
passwd=passwordField.getText();
return true;
  }
  else{ return false; }
}
public void showMessage(String message){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
final GridBagConstraints gbc = 
  new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                         GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                         GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                         new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
private Container panel;
public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                          String name,
                                          String instruction,
                                          String[] prompt,
                                          boolean[] echo){
  panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

  gbc.weightx = 1.0;
  gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
  gbc.gridx = 0;
  panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
  gbc.gridy++;

  gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

  JTextField[] texts=new JTextField[prompt.length];
  for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]),gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    if(echo[i]){
      texts[i]=new JTextField(20);
    }
    else{
      texts[i]=new JPasswordField(20);
    }
    panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
  }

  if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                                   destination+": "+name,
                                   JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
     ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
    for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
      response[i]=texts[i].getText();
    }
return response;
  }
  else{
    return null;  // cancel
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me a simple example pleas, using jsch.

Comment: I wonder, why are not you trying the example at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/X11Forwarding.java.